# JNI Error "No implementation found for" -> Android Standalone Toolchain

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, g++

I compiling a shared library (.so) to use in my Android App.

I am compiling this library with a standalone toolchain.

When running this app via the Android Virtual Device (AVD), the shared library is loaded and running without any problems on the x86 platform. Below are my commands for compiling for x86.

- i686-linux-android26-clang -I-I/home/veda/android-ndk-r21/sysroot/usr/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -static-libgcc -march=i686 -mtune=intel -mssse3 -mfpmath=sse -m32 -fPIC
- i686-linux-android26-clang++ -I-I/home/veda/android-ndk-r21/sysroot/usr/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -static-libstdc++ -march=i686 -mtune=intel -mssse3 -mfpmath=sse -m32 -fPIC

**However when attempting to load the library on to a phone (Google Pixel) the following error is shown. The google pixel is arm64 platform. Below are my commands for compiling for arm64. Any Ideas?**

- aarch64-linux-android-gcc -I/home/veda/android-ndk-r21/build/toolchain/sysroot/usr/include/android -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -static-libgcc -fPIC
- aarch64-linux-android-g++ -I/home/veda/android-ndk-r21/build/toolchain/sysroot/usr/include/android -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -static-libstdc++ -fPIC

**Error:**

```
E/linker: "/data/app/com.example.androidsharedlibscratch-a6Mv8edOnQ2q6HbbixecrQ==/lib/arm64/libToon-c.so": ignoring DT_PREINIT_ARRAY in shared library! E/haredlibscratc: No implementation found for long com.example.androidsharedlibscratch.Toon.createToon() (tried Java_com_example_androidsharedlibscratch_Toon_createToon and Java_com_example_androidsharedlibscratch_Toon_createToon__) D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.androidsharedlibscratch, PID: 18368
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.example.androidsharedlibscratch.Toon.createToon() (tried Java_com_example_androidsharedlibscratch_Toon_createToon and Java_com_example_androidsharedlibscratch_Toon_createToon__)
        at com.example.androidsharedlibscratch.Toon.createToon(Native Method)
        at com.example.androidsharedlibscratch.Toon.<init>(Toon.java:44)
        at com.example.androidsharedlibscratch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Please add enough code to give us a minimally complete reproducible example, as well as the commands to create the actual .so file.

Comment: Is it possible you are linking object files (.o) compiled for x86 into the binary for arm64?